# adding a directory of images to android project

Tags: java, android, image, directory, ocr

I am developing an OCR app and I need to have a directory full of training images for the OCR to train. How would I add those images to the project? (I'm relatively new to android)
I understand there are different drawable folders for images but I assume I want a folder separate from all of those.

All help appreciated thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

Put them in the `assets/` folder.

Android won't try to scale them (or do anything else to them) if you place those in there.

If we're talking about gigs of images, then place them manually on your sdcard and have you app retrieve them when it needs them.